# HyperLedger Fabric:Current leader peer of the organisation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have configured the Peer leader to be dynamic, By specifying

```
export CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
export CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
```

in the peer configuration of both peer1 and peer2. How can I know which is the current leader peer after I start the network ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the metrics provided by the [operations endpoint](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/operations_service.html).

If you enable the Prometheus provider, the metric is `gossip_leader_election_leader` labelled by channel.

If you enable the statsd provider, the metric is `gossip.leader_election.leader.%{channel}`.

In either case, 0 = follower, 1 = leader.